What is the P=NP? building?
I remember that I read somewhere some years ago that they've built a computing building with the 'P=NP?' question built in it from bricks so that they later have the option to rearrange these bricks to form $P \neq NP$ or $P=NP$. Now I cannot find anything about this at all. What is this building?
ChatGPT thinks it is the Gates Computer Science Building at Stanford University, but I couldn't verify this in any way.
ps. This should be tagged soft-question, but apparently this site doesn't have that tag.

My question has been answered after cross-posting at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54217 by Wei Zhan, the solution was the Princeton CS Building: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/general/bricks.
